# What element am I typing into?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On this page, what element is receiving the text as you type?

I need to get the text value of the element, but I can't seem to find it.

http://featuredfotografer.com/

If someone could show me how to get this specific text value with jQuery it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".CodeMirror-lines div:last").text();`

It's not a single element. It's creating tags and indents on the fly... but the above will return the text value of everything inside the last `div` of `.CodeMirror-lines`, which I believe is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.CodeMirror > div').find('textarea').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got some tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) it would make finding elements like this easy

Comment: i am already using google's dev panel, i just couldn't find it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome's (awesome) developer tools, I found out that it is a hidden `textarea` and then it uses divs & spans to style it with colors on the fly in a separate element (**not** in the textarea because you can't style text in a normal `textarea`) as you type text:

[image]

So you can use this code to get the text that is typed in:

```
$('#code').val();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i would have seen that. it is the first solution

Comment: @maxhud Okay, well if this answers your question (it should - it does exactly what you wanted) then please accept my answer :)

Comment: it doesn't do what i want. when you change the value of the text, the value of that textarea doesn't change. look at the solution i upvoted who i will be accepting the answer from

Comment: @maxhud Oh ok, I didn't know that, no need to have an attitude about it.